# SwiftUI NavigationLink with custom binding based on dictionary fails to reset after transitioning back

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a dictionary that stores string -> bool, in my view, I wrap this dictionary around a `Binding<Bool>` to be able to store the states of each `NavigationLink` in order to later be able to programmatically navigate. Now, this works the first time, Page 1 -> Page 2 -> Page 3, but when you hit back to Page 2, the navigation stops working.

I have checked that the values of `isLinkActive` dictionary do correctly get updated when `NavigationLink` is tapped, however, `NavigationLink` does not get activated.

```
import SwiftUI

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLinkActive:[String: Bool] = [:]
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()

    var page3: some View {
        Text("Page 3")
    }

    @State var data = ["1", "2", "3"]

    func binding(chatId: String) -> Binding<Bool> {
        return .init(get: { () -> Bool in
            return self.contentViewModel.isLinkActive[chatId, default: false]
        }) { (value) in
            self.contentViewModel.isLinkActive[chatId] = value
        }
    }

    var page2: some View {
        return
            List(data, id: \.self) { data in
                NavigationLink(destination: self.page3, isActive: self.binding(chatId: data)) {
                    Text("Page \(data) Link")
                }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView() {
            VStack {
                Text("Page 1")
                NavigationLink(destination: page2) {
                    Text("Page 2 Link")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use this for "back-to-level" then it will not work, because NavigationView does not store all active stack, but only current navigation link, so only one-step back is possible. Just in case, be aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the logic of your code. The only issue is that SwiftUI *doesn't* redraw `page2` as it only redraws the `var body` during an `onAppear`, and this view is not in context. The way to force refresh is thus to make `page2` a body variable.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView() {
            VStack {
                Text("Page 1")
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewTwo()) {
                    Text("Page 2 Link")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentViewTwo: View {

  @ObservedObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()

  var page3: some View {
      Text("Page 3")
  }

  @State var data = ["1", "2", "3"]

  func binding(chatId: String) -> Binding<Bool> {
      return .init(get: { () -> Bool in
          return self.contentViewModel.isLinkActive[chatId, default: false]
      }) { (value) in
          self.contentViewModel.isLinkActive[chatId] = value
      }
  }

  var body: some View {
      return
          List(data, id: \.self) { data in
              NavigationLink(destination: self.page3, isActive: self.binding(chatId: data)) {
                  Text("Page \(data) Link")
              }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, thank you! Is there any documentation about the root cause or about how onAppear/views are redrawn?